# Does a DB 1st class ticket with Eurostar component correspond to Business Premier or to Standard Premier?

Tags: trains, germany, eurostar

DB has two classes: Second Class and First Class.

Eurostar has [three classes](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/travel-planning/travel-classes): Business Premier, Standard Premier, and Standard.

DB sells tickets that include Eurostar travel.

A DB second class ticket including Eurostar travel corresponds to Standard class on the Eurostar.

What Eurostar class does the Eurostar component of a DB first class ticket including Eurostar travel correspond to?  Business Premier or Standard Premier?

Although the seats are the same between Business Premier and Standard Premier, the Business Premier ticket comes with (better/more) food and lounge access, among other things.  The DB ticket says checkin 45 minutes in advance, but [Eurostar Business Premier](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/travel-planning/travel-classes/business-premier) says the traveller can *breeze through just ten minutes before departure*.

Does it make any difference whether the DB ticket is regular or Sparpreis?

Comment: From memory, which is why this is a comment not an answer, I think I got into the lounge in Brussels but was in a Standard Premier coach. Seems a bit weird if true so perhaps my memory is going, It would have been a London Spezial ticket as they were called then.

Comment: I thought Standard Premier and Business Premier coaches were the same and differences were only in conditions and service level?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is why I cannot remember which I was in. At this length of time I cannot remember the meal I got.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was a difference resulting from being on a regular ticket or Sparpreis. Usually with DB the only difference between those is price and conditions (cancellation, changes, ...).

Comment: @mts The reason I mention it is because on Eurostar, Standard Premier tickets are semi-flexible whereas Business Premier tickets are fully flexible.  A Business Premier ticket can be rebooked to a later Eurostar departure at any time before departure, at no cost.  This is true for a regular First Class DB ticket, but certainly not for a Sparpreis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was treated as a **Standard Premier** passenger.

I **did not** get access to the Eurostar lounge.

I **did not** get to use the special express check-in gate.

I **did** get food on-board like other Eurostar Standard Premier passengers.