# For a Eurostar ticket booked through Deutsche Bahn, how do I request a special meal?

Tags: trains, germany, eurostar

I have a Eurostar ticket booked through Deutsche Bahn.  It is a first class ticket, so it [should correspond](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/118402/2509) to one of the classes that includes meals.  To pre-order vegetarian meals, [Eurostar advices](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/your-trip/food-on-board) to *request special meals in our Manage a booking section*.  However, the *manage a booking* section on the Eurostar website is not available for tickets booked through Deutsche Bahn.  How can I still request a special meal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I [asked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/gerrit_holl/status/1017778812631879683) and was told to contact them directly through Twitter direct message, attaching a picture of my ticket and the specific request.

After I did so, they confirmed a special meal had been ordered for me.  They seemed a little confused about the absence of a 6-letter code but I assumed it would work out, and indeed it did.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, email them. Explain as you did here, they are in the best position to answer your questions.